# Calculating the average of a raster in raster calculator

Tags: raster-calculator

I have a raster containing trout sightings spanning back to the 1800's and I want to calculate the average of all the data and then compare this to the  year with the most sightings.

Can anyone explain how to go about this please?

I can't seem to find any help about this elsewhere.

Comment: Could you expand what software you are using? If it is ArcMap what licenses do you have access to? If you could add a picture or snippet of the data it will help people understand your problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using QGIS and have the processing plugin installed just search for statistics in the toolbox and it will give you several algorithms to calculate raster statistics. For example the 'Raster layer statistics' algorithm under QGIS geoalgorithms -> Raster tools is such a tool that does the job. It will give you the min, max, mean, sum and standard deviation for example.

In ArcMap you can rightclick on the raster layer and under the 'Source' tab it will give you the statistics.